# Send obstacles from right side of screen in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a basic dodger game where you play as a fish and need to avoid getting hit by obstacles. I want the obstacles to come from the right side of the screen at a random velocity (from a certain range, let's just say 4 to 6). I already have the fish/underwater gravity mechanics working. But I have no idea where to start with the obstacles.

This is my main python script:

```
import pygame
from assets.player import Bob

# Screen properties

pygame.init()

# Important Variables

run = True
game_speed = 0

SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 900, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

# Properties

bg_game_surface = pygame.image.load('images/game-background.png')
player = Bob(game_speed)

#############
# Functions #
#############

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.blit(bg_game_surface, (0, 0))
    player.update(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

And this is the class for my player:

```
import pygame

class Bob:
    def __init__(self, game_speed):
        self.img = pygame.image.load('images/player/bob.png').convert_alpha()
        self.img_up = pygame.image.load('images/player/bob_up.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.img.get_rect()

        self.game_speed = game_speed

    def update(self, screen):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        ### Collision

        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.centery = (screen.get_height() - self.img.get_height() * 2) + 10

        elif self.rect.top >= screen.get_height() - self.img.get_height() * 2:
            self.rect.centery = 20


        ### Movement

        if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.centery -= 6
            self.img = pygame.image.load('images/player/bob_up.png').convert_alpha()

        ### Gravity

        else:
            self.img = pygame.image.load('images/player/bob.png').convert_alpha()
            self.rect.centery += 4

        screen.blit(self.img, self.rect)
```

My folders are sorted like this:

[image: Image of folder sorting]

Right now, I'd like that the trash.py is also a class with a function called "update". When that function is executed, obstacles (preferably in the form of an image) come out of the right side of the display, doing what I said above.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: first, don't load the images in the `update` method, you already have them loaded, just in the `if/else` use sth like `img = self.image` and `img = self.img_up`, then just `screen.blit(img, self.rect)`, loading images ain't cheap

Comment: Look into sprite classes in pygame. Then simply make a sprite group for the obstacles and call the update() method of the sprite group. And in that update you can do the movement.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a [sprite class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) group, but first you need to import the random module:

```
import random
```

Now you can create the Obstacle Sprite class, **this is just an example**:

```
class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos): #pos is the starting position
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10,10)) # You can change this with pygame.image.load('...')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.vel = random.randint(4,6) #random speed of the obstacle
    def collisions(self, player): #collisions function
        if self.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
            print('collision!') #write what you want to happen
    def movement(self): #the blocks are moving left
        if self.rect.x > -100: #just putting some limits
            self.rect.x -= self.vel
    def update(self, player): #try to put all the other functions in the update one
        
        self.collisions(player)
        
        self.movement()
```

Once you created the class, you only need to create some objects of that class (every obstacle).
First we create a [sprite group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) before of the while loop:

```
obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Then, inside your main loop, you need a condition that generates the obstacles.
I've done something like this, but you really should change it:

```
if x < 10: #I created x before the while (x=0)
        posx = SCREEN_WIDTH + 50 #the starting x will be 50 pixels right of the screen
        posy = random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT) #Im setting this to random
        obs = Obstacle((posx, posy))
        obstacles.add(obs)
        x +=1
```

This basically creates 9 obstacles when we start the game, with different random x speed and y location, and [draw](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) them on the screen. If you collide with one of the blocks, the code just prints "collision!" (see the Obstacle class). Hope it was helpful and I didn't miss something.